# Internal HDD became very slow

Tags: windows, hard-drive, performance

I have 1TB WD internal HDD. It's very slower for instance when I try to format it and put a windows on it, it takes forever to install so I try to use it as storage drive. When I try to copy some files to that drive it starts with pretty cool speed rate of 40mbps and then it then drop by 300kbps and suddenly increasing and lowering like that. So anyone know what problem might be it is
??

Comment: Possible hard disk failure. Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive's SMART status in Windows 7?](//superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](//superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.

Comment: Run HD Tune and check SMART status + a read bad sector test.